# Can't position div below another div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a website, with my basic knowledge, for my mother. But I've tried many things, but I can't get it to work the way I want it to

This is how it now looks:

[image]

And this is how I want it to be:

[image]

But somehow I can't get it to work. The div isn't positioning where I want it to position.

This is my source code: 
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/afrv9w61/3/)

It's about this part that doesn't position properly:

```
 <div class="wrapper_3">
    <div class="main_3">
        3
    </div>
 </div>
```

Thanks in advance for the help! I really can't get it to work.

Comment: you could work on the wrapper_3 by add a new rule: 'margin-top'

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't work if you change the resolution of your screen

Comment: margin-top: x% ... where x could be (for example) 160 ... 
anyway your css is not so elegant... did u ever consider to use bootstrap with his grid system?

Comment: No i didnt, is it better to use bootstrap?

Comment: yes, http://getbootstrap.com/css/
read about the grid system ... it's easy and powerful

Answer (score 1):

Add `float:left;` to `wrapper_1` and `wrapper_2`

after that, use `position:relative;` to position `wrapper_2`.

visit this link if you need more information about syntax.
[CSS Position Property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_relative)
 Here is your new CSS.

```
.wrapper_1 {    width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 21%;
  margin-top: 14%;
  clear: both;
    float:left;}


 .wrapper_2 {
      width: 25%;

      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: 16px;
      margin-top: 5%;
        float:left;
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

it will be easier if you use bootstrap for your website.

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <div class="logo text-center">logo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-3 box">2</div>
            <div class="col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-3 box">1</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

css:

```
.logo {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding: 15px;

}
.box {
    padding: 60px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/souraj/sxuqqqgd/

here you can see the code.
you have to link the bootstrap.css file to work. just visit to getbootstrap.com and see how to link bootstrap.css in your code.add this code to your head section of the code.
[enter link description here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

Comment: you have to link the bootstrap.css file to work. just visit to getbootstrap.com and see how to link bootstrap.css in your code. <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: No, it will not be _easier_ to use bootstrap, even for motivated, yet inexperienced developer, to build his website

Comment: i just suggested him to use bootstrap because it is easier to create a website using bootstrap.

Comment: In general it's easier to do things you know how to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :) I  edited your fiddle, Why are you using position:absolute; everywhere? There is no need of absolute positioning in your design.

```css
* { 
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0; 
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper_logo {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width:20%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}

.wrapper_logo:after {
  padding-top: 45%;
  /* 16:9 ratio */
  display: block;
  content: '';
}

.main_logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    color: black;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.wrapper_1 {
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 21%;
  margin-top: 14%;
  clear: both;
}

.wrapper_1:after {
  padding-top: 56.10%;
  /* 16:9 ratio */
  display: block;
  content: '';
  clear: both;
}

.main_1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  color: white;
}

.wrapper_2 {
  width: 25%;
  margin-left:200px;
}

.wrapper_2:after {
  padding-top: 56.10%;
  /* 16:9 ratio */
  display: block;
  content: '';
}

.main_2 {

  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  color: white;
}

.wrapper_3 {
  width: 15%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}

.wrapper_3:after {
  padding-top: 56.10%;
  /* 16:9 ratio */
  display: block;
  content: '';
}

.main_3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  color: white;
}

.three {
  position: absolute; 
  background: green; 
  width: 400px; 
  top: 10px; 
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <div class="main">
    
      <div class="wrapper_logo">
    <div class="main_logo">
     LOGO
    </div>
   </div>

         <div class="wrapper_1">
    <div class="main_1">
     1
       </div>
   </div>

   <div class="wrapper_2">
    <div class="main_2">
     2
       </div>
   </div>

   <!-- <div class="wrapper_3">
    <div class="main_3">
     3
       </div>
   </div> -->
  </div>
```